# Importing SQL Server table (or view) into MS Word 2013

Tags: sql-server, ms-word, odbc

I would like to insert an object to my MS Word 2013 document, which would be a table with data from SQL Server database table or view (preferably via ODBC).
Ideally with refreshing mechanism (a button or something like that).

Is there any way I can do it within MS Word (or some common add-ons)?
What I have found so far is only [this](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Import-data-into-Office-Publisher-Visio-or-Word-by-using-the-Data-Connection-Wizard-65295a62-8da3-49bc-8dd8-1f77d0a05127#bmwordsqlsodbc), however I guess it's only for mail merging.
If it's not possible to insert such table directly, a solution with MS Excel or Access can also do the job.

Thanks!
Michal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an answer to that.

1) Add "Insert Database" button to task bar ([instruction here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/word-2010-where-is-the-insert-database-command-or/d4a9bd42-44a6-4841-b9a4-ec8dc789c684))

2) Click "Insert Database" and follow the wizard to add the data source.

3) Add filters, sorting and formatting (Query Options/Table Autoformat)

4) Click "Insert Data" and the table is inserted - you can also check the checkbox if the table is supposed to refresh on doc opening.

Watch outs:

1) Inserting big tables or views take some time.

2) I cannot see anything like "refresh table" button. The only way to refresh data is to close and re-open the doc (providing that the apropriate checkbox was checked before) or re-create the table - if anyone has a better idea here, please commment

Answer (score -2):

In Excel, you can use the Data tab -> From Other Sources -> From Microsoft Query. Then choose the ODBC data source and the table you want.